# npm install を実行するとフリーズしてしまう

Tags: npm

Windows 10 の環境で、

```
npm install -g @uniqys/cli
```

上記のコマンドを実行したいのですが、途中でフリーズしてしまいます。下の画像の状態のまま動かなくなってしまいました。

[image: 実際の実行画面です]

Comment: 状況がまだよくわかりませんので、`npm install -g @uniqys/cli --loglevel silly` を実行した結果を教えて頂けないでしょうか。非常に多くのログが出ますが、止まってしまったときの最後10行くらいあれば十分かと思います。ログを質問に追記していただけると助かります。

Answer (score -1):

メッセージ "npm WARN This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to tha latest version"
[直訳]　npm 警告：　このバージョンは保守・管理されていません。　最新のバージョンにアップグレードしてください。

という内容のメッセージが出ています。

その意味するところは
『お使いのマシンに保存されている（ダウンロードしてある）パッケージが保守対象から外れた古いものなので、インストールするのはヤバイです（だから、インストールしませんでした）。
最新バージョンのものに更新して、それをインストールしましょうよ』

だから、アップグレード（更新）すれば問題解決するのではないでしょうか。

> npm update @uniqys/cli

で、@uniqys/cliパッケージを更新してから

> npm install -g @uniqys/cli

で、@uniqys/cliパッケージのインストールをしてみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
アップデートをして再度試してみたのですが同じ状態でフリーズしてしまいました。

Comment: アップデートは成功しましたか（npm updateの前後でバージョンが上がりましたか？）